# Querying DataFrame column with special characters using df.query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like:

```
    cat.c1         cat.c2          cat.c3           name
0   tony           NaN              NaN             groupA
1   Magoo          {}               NaN             groupA
2   Jon            NaN              {}              groupA
```

Queries such as

```
df.query('name=="groupA"')
```

But I want to query on a prefixed column.

I try:
    df.query('cat.c1=="tony"')

I get:

```
KeyError: 'cat'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query` has limitations on what columns you can query with it. A rule of thumb I like to follow is that, if the name isn't a valid python identifier name, then it just won't work.

Your only option is to index directly with a boolean max.

```
df[df['cat.c1'] == "tony"]
```

Alternatively, you may want to get rid of those pesky prefixes, or just join them altogether.

```
df.columns.str.split('.').str.join('_')
Index(['cat_c1', 'cat_c2', 'cat_c3', 'name'], dtype='object')
```

Assign the column names back, and you can then use `query`:

```
df.query('cat_c1 == "tony"')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enclose columns in back quotes it will also work